# How can I remove gaps of 0.1 seconds in sox?

Tags: linux, command-line, command-line-interface, sox

im use this command  but i dont know how I could change the values for 0.1 seconds

```
sox spokenxh.wav spokenx.wav  silence 1 0.2 0.5% -1 0.2 0.5%
```

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try
sox spokenxh.wav spokenx.wav  silence 1 0.1 0.5% -1 0.2 0.5%

or check the link 
https://digitalcardboard.com/blog/2009/08/25/the-sox-of-silence/comment-page-2/